# Using an ampersand in flying saucer

Tags: java, html, pdf, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I get the error below when converting to PDF with flying saucer. I've removed the ampersand charector and it worked, so this seems to be the problem. How do I include ampersand's in my PDF documents? Thanks in advance.

> ERROR:  'The entity name must
>   immediately follow the '&' in the
>   entity reference.'

Comment: try replacing it with '%26' and see if that works.

Comment: without the quotes, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace & with `&amp;`

NOTE:That won't work for filenames, just content.

Answer (score 2):

Flying saucer parses only valid xhtml.  With XML you would have to define your & entity.  However, I've stopped trying to use & and have started using:

```
&#38;
```

That is your ampersand that will work with xhtml, and it will work with Flying saucer to get the ampersand into the PDF.

Useful Reference: http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape any XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos). An easy and effective way to do this is by using the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library function [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem, but I solved it by surrounding the conflict characters (like &)  with the

```
<![CDATA['&']]>
```

notation. Hope it helps as well, because the previous answers did not work for me.